# How do i set up data memory address when using "riscv32/64-unknown-elf-gcc"?

Tags: gcc, riscv

I designed RISCV32IM processor, and i used "riscv32/64-unknown-elf-gcc" to generate code for test.
Instruction memory setting has been solved with the options below(-Ttext option), but data memory setting has not been solved yet.

```
riscv64-unknown-elf-gcc -v -march=rv32im -mabi=ilp32 -nostartfiles -x c  -Ttext 40000000 -o main.o main.c
```

Can I know if I can set the data memory address I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

looks like you need to link `linker script`, something like:

```
OUTPUT_ARCH( "riscv" )
ENTRY(_start)

SECTIONS
{
  . = 0x40000000;
  .text.init : { *(.text.init) }
  . = ALIGN(0x1000);
  .text : { *(.text) }
  . = ALIGN(0x1000);
  .data : { *(.data) }
  .bss : { *(.bss) }
  _end = .;
}
```

- `_start` is a start symbol and 0x40000000 is a memory start address,
  followed by the section names aligned by 0x1000.
- `text` this is the program itself
- `data` is a statically initialized variables
- `bss`
  is a statically allocated variables

Comment: Thank you for your help! I solved the problem by using the command below. "riscv64-unknown-elf-gcc -v -march=rv32im -mabi=ilp32 -nostartfiles -x c  -Ttext 40000000 -Tdata 50000000 -Tbss 60000000 -o main.o main.c"

Comment: I have one more question. 
Huge code was generated when compiling using malloc() function.
The riscv32im processor (I designed) works without an OS and should run in an environment with severely small memory size.
Is it possible to generate code that only accesses allocated data memory using the malloc() function?
"*(volatile unsigned int *) 0xf10007fc = (int ) 0x4;" I wish there was a way to avoid using this kind of code over and over again.

Comment: I recommend you use a linker file, it's simpler, but of course whatever you want. If your code is tiny, you may no to use malloc / free, but you must be clear about your memory size limits! In this case, you read / write memory addresses directly. I always do this when there are so few programs and there are many loops in them. Or even using assembler language.

Comment: Thank you your answer!!
I also used malloc() and free() function.
A part of the assembly code of the compilation result using these functions is as follows.
malloc(), free(), and malloc_r() functions are created as codes.
I want to get the same result as the code with direct memory access.

"400000c4 <malloc>:"
"400000d0 <free>:"
"400000dc <_malloc_r>:"